# What is the best way to explain the transfer matrix method?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, education

In some notes I'm writing I would like to briefly explain how to use the transfer matrix method to derive a Markov chain solution to the one-dimensional Ising model. (Or rather a generalised version of it, but that need not concern us here.) My problem is that although I understand the results I'm presenting very well I'm not sure how best to motivate them. It's easy enough to say "we guess that this is the solution" and then verify that indeed it is, but in the context I'd prefer to derive it instead, so that it doesn't appear to come from nowhere.

To be precise, I would like to explain the result presented in Yvan Velnik's great answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/216611/what-are-alternative-ways-to-think-about-transfer-matrix-as-used-in-ising-model/), which says that if one forms the transfer matrix $T$ for a one dimensional Ising type model, one can then form another matrix $P$ with elements $P_{ij} = \frac{T_{ij}v_j}{\lambda v_i}$, where $\lambda$ and $v$ are the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue and eigenvector of $T$. The matrix $P$ is a stochastic matrix, and the solution to the Ising-type model is given by its stationary distribution.

I can easily verify this result, and I can also derive it for myself from first principles. The problem is that my derivation feels more like what a mathematician would do than what a physicist would do, and I think most physicists would find it unnecessarily long-winded and not easy to understand. So what I want to know is, how can I go from the transfer matrix $T$ to the stochastic matrix $P$ in a way that's straightforward and intuitive for physicists?

Comment: Did you ever find a good explanation?

Comment: @AnotherUser if I were writing it today, I'd probably do it like this: First, form the matrix $T$ with entries $e^{-\beta E_{ij}}$, where $E_{ij}$ is the energy between two neighbouring spins if one is in state i and the other in state j. Then solve for a finite chain of $n$ spins, say with fixed boundary conditions, and notice that to do that you're multiplying the matrix $T$ by itself lots of times and then rescaling (the factor of $1/Z$). As you take the infinite $n$ limit you're multiplying $T$ by itself an infinite number of times, so it will converge to its Perron-Frobenius eigenvector.

Comment: @AnotherUser that's obviously all a bit sketched out, but when you work through the details the matrix $P$ arises naturally. It's not *completely* straightforward, and I think when I first came across it some of the steps seemed a bit mysterious, but when you've worked it all out for yourself a few times it starts to feel inevitable.