# Hammersley-Clifford theorem and maximal entropy random walk for Ising-like models?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, ising-model, spin-statistics

It seems that condensed matter people usually just brute force use Monte-Carlo, but there are some subtle mathematical tools which might be worth considering, for example:

1) **Hammersley-Clifford theorem** ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammersley%E2%80%93Clifford_theorem ) saying that Gibbs fields are equivalent with Markov fields, which allow to simplify models, e.g. through local Markov condition:

**Pr(value in node|remaining nodes) = Pr(value in node|its neighbors)**

2) **Maximal entropy random walk** ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_Entropy_Random_Walk ) provides probability distribution of patterns for Boltzmann ensemble of infinite sequences. Applying it to transition matrix (M_uv = exp(-beta E_uv) for neighboring patterns), while there are usually used its eigenvalues, here from its dominant eigenvector we get probability distribution of patterns e.g. in 2D Ising model:

$$Pr(u)=(\psi_u)^2\qquad Pr(uv) = \psi_u \frac{M_{uv}}{\lambda} \psi_v\qquad \textrm{for argmax}_{|\lambda|}\  M\psi=\lambda \psi$$

Is there a literature for applying any of them for Ising-like models?

---

I ask because I have just  [written paper using both](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.13300) - calculating in seconds parameters for Ising-like models with many digits of accuracy, also probability distribution of patterns or allowing to generate new uncorrelated field with single scan - and don't know what to cite?

Diagram from the paper with concepts and plots of errors: [image]

Comment: I won't comment much on the applications to sampling, as I am not an expert. First, I am unsure what you are looking for concerning the Hammersley-Clifford theorem: it seems to me that the standard Gibbs sampler algorithm is relying on this fact (although, probably not citing the Hammersley-Clifford theorem as a justification).

Comment: Moreover, while I am not familiar with the "maximal entropy random walk", the expressions you write that relate transfer matrices with Markov chains are well-known in the (rigorous) statistical mechanics community; see, e.g., [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/218439) and the reference given in the comments following it.

Comment: So, my point is: you'd have more chance of getting an answer if you clarified what kind of information you are expecting.

Comment: @YvanVelenik, thanks I have only seen eigenvalues of transition matrix e.g. in Baxter, not eigenvector with this this Born-like rule. Monte-Carlo sampling indeed has some connection with local Markov property, but this property is a bit different - allows to reduce context for conditional distribution of patterns. I am just asking for literature, do you maybe know some papers toward analyzis of probability distribution of patterns e.g. in 2D Ising?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I don't have any work of that type in mind. Of course, there are works investigating statistical properties of local patterns in, say, the Ising model (see, for instance, [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1276867298) and references therein), but their goal is very different from what you are interested in. Related ideas may have been used by people doing simulations, but my knowledge of this area is pretty poor.